# Keep ViewController loaded after navigating

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, view, ios5

Currently I am making an application with a lot of views.

I want it, so that in the application when the user navigates away from a view (after he/she has entered data into the UITextViews UITextFeilds UILabels etc.) he/she will be able to come back later and see it the same way they left it as.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this easily for I have a lot of views.
Basically is there a way to do this by simply not dismissing the view?

I don't want to have to use the:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have strong pointers for your `viewControllers` in your application delegate class.

Than you can assign that pointer to the `viewControllers` you mentioned for the first time they appear.

Than in the `viewWillAppear` method of your controllers you can null check that pointers and exchanged the current view to the stored one in your application delegate.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean? Also I am using    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to dismiss the view